# Active voice, "Do not smoke" to passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

The following sentence is in the active voice: "Do not smoke."

What is its equivalent in the passive voice?

1- Let the smoke not be done.

or

2- Smoking is prohibited.

Comment: Active = He smokes cigars. Passive: Cigars are smoked by him. Do not smoke is not active voice. It's an imperative: Do this or Don't do that.

Comment: @Lambie Correct me if I'm wrong, but imperatives have voice too, and "do not smoke" is definitely active. "Do not be deceived" is a passive imperative.

Comment: If you are trying to make a sign, it is common to see signs that say "No smoking" or "This is a smoke free facility."

Comment: @brianpck - But is that really passive?  "Do not be" is exactly the same structure as "Do not smoke".

Comment: @stangdon Of course: in English the passive is formed by using the active form of "be" + past participle

Comment: @brianpck - Yes, that is how you normally form a passive sentence, but I'm not sure that that makes your example a "passive imperative".  [Everything I've seen about the passive imperative uses **let**.](http://www.englishgrammar.org/changing-imperative-sentence-active-voice-passive/)

Comment: "Dear cigars, please do not be smoked"

Comment: @stangdon About that quote from your linked resource, ("**do** is not used in the passive form"), there is another way of forming the passive imperative without using "do" but also without the auxiliary "let": *"Be [S] [V]ed."* (A great example is in older translations of the Book of Genesis where instead of "Let there be light," you'll find "Be light made.") So for brianpck's example, the other passive form would be "Be not deceived." This structure does seem kind of antiquated or at least very formal in comparison with the alternatives ("do" and "let").

Answer (score 9):

"Smoking is prohibited" is a very common formulation, e.g.

- "Lihue Airport is a no smoking facility.  Smoking is prohibited from "cabin to curb” at the airport." ([Lihue Airport](http://hawaii.gov/lih/customer-service/smoking))
- Smoking is prohibited in public places in X.
- Places where smoking is prohibited include: (...).

Note that this is not a passive version of "Do not smoke", since this sentence cannot be transformed into the passive voice. It is an [imperative form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English) that has neither an explicit subject, nor an explicit direct object.

**Update**:

The form "Do not be smoked" (from a comment by Colin Fine) is unusual and would not be addressed to a smoker but to something that would undergo the act of smoking.

Comment: There is a passive - "Do not be smoked" - but it has a completely different meaning, since it is addressed to the cigarette etc, not to the smoker.

Comment: It would be a little weird if it was addressed to the smoker.

Comment: Even weirder if addressed to the cigarette.

Comment: Just to add something else you'll see frequently, "No Smoking" is very common sign you'll see at businesses, schools, etc. In america at least

Comment: Do not smoke is an imperative.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply the passive is:

> Do not be smoked.

Remember that *passive* reverses the roles of object and subject. You are no longer the one doing the smoking in passive voice.

To use @brianpck's example from his comment, "do not be deceived" implies that someone is potentially deceiving you, while it's active counterpart, "do not deceive" implies that you are potentially deceiving someone else.

If you want to preserve the meaning then you would have to expose the implied direct object (and imply the subject), but an imperative statement is necessarily directed at the second person (usually not an inanimate object), so it's not really possible.

The best you could do is look at that cigar square in the face and tell it:

> "Hey cigar, do not be smoked"